# setImageResource wont work, ListView model.xml

Tags: android, xml, image, listview

I have problems to use a "if" condition to **change an image** from my **model.xml**. Every time  run the program the following **error below** is displayed. **If i change "if" condition to show Toast Msg for example, the program works normally** and "if" works very well for toast displaying the msg, but with this "**setImageResource**" **don´t work**. How do I change an image from my model.xml using this condition? **Thanks to all**

**Model.xml:** //model for ListView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iRetorno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tConvenio"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sem_retorno" />
```

**Code:** //All QuerySQL_Consulta method

```
public void QuerySQL_Consulta(String COMANDOSQL){
    ResultSet rs;
    quantidade=0;

    try{

        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(COMANDOSQL);

        //CONFIGURAR O SIMPLE ADAPTER

        ListaConsulta = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        //RESULTSET, TODOS OS REGISTROS
        while(rs.next()){
            Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A", rs.getString("convenio"));
            datanum.put("B", rs.getString("paciente"));
            datanum.put("C", rs.getString("procedimento"));
            datanum.put("D", rs.getString("retorno"));
            if(datanum.get("D").equals("S")){
                //RETORNO.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_retorno);
            }
            ListaConsulta.add(datanum);
            quantidade++;
        }

        String[] from = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
        int[] lista_consulta = {R.id.tConvenio, R.id.tPaciente, R.id.tProcedimento, R.id.tRetorno};

        //MODELO LAYOUT
        AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, ListaConsulta, R.layout.modelo, from, lista_consulta);
        RESULTADO.setAdapter(AD);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("ERRO: ",e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**StackTrace:**

> 03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at com.example.clinicmobile.MainActivity.QuerySQL_Consulta(MainActivity.java:196)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at com.example.clinicmobile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:218)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   03-12 22:45:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(14330):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**UPDATE 13/03/2014**

I have **set 2 imageview** now, **one imageview in "activity_main.xml" called "INFO" and the other imageview in "modelo.xml" called "RETORNO"**. Changed my while resultset and add this 2 imageviews. setImageResource for "INFO in activity_main.xml" **WORKS**, but for "RETORNO in modelo.xml" **WON´T WORK**.

```
while(rs.next()){
            Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A", rs.getString("convenio"));
            datanum.put("B", rs.getString("paciente"));
            datanum.put("C", rs.getString("procedimento"));
            datanum.put("D", rs.getString("retorno"));
            if(datanum.get("D").equals("N")){
                INFO.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_retorno);
                RETORNO.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_retorno);
            }
```

**StackTrace** Using "**RETORNO**" give me this error

> 03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at com.example.clinicmobile.MainActivity.QuerySQL_Consulta(MainActivity.java:198)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at com.example.clinicmobile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:220)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   03-13 22:42:19.223: E/AndroidRuntime(16702):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post the whole QuerySQL_Consulta method

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message at com.example.clinicmobile.MainActivity.QuerySQL_Consulta(MainActivity.java:196). You are logging a null value probably.

Comment: I think the problem is how i referece RETORNO.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_retorno) to imageview of model.xml. Have tested this setImageResource for change imageview for activity_main.xml and works